# How to remove other UI components in ios

Tags: ios4

In my app i am having following scenario

1. There is thread running in background which check some flag is on or not
2. This thread is running for entire application.
3. If flag found "on" then go to some view (pushed from navigationcontroller)
4. So i need to discard or remove all other UI components like UIAlertView ,UIActionSheet etc

In my case when i pushed the view controller then actionsheet open is not discarded automatically

How can i remove all other UI Components already initiated whenever the view is pushed

Please do write to this thread

Thnx in advance

Parag Deshpande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-(void)removeSubView:(UIView *view)
{
  NSArray* arr =view.subViews;
  for(UIView* tmp in arr)
  {

}

Comment: thnx vinay where should i define this  i mean in every viewcontroller or in my thread

Comment: you can define it in your own view controller and call it in dealloc and didReceiveMemoryWarning() and where you want to remove view .

Comment: thnx again however i am not getting uiactionsheet refernce in array of subviews.